# ListFieldIterator doesn't return value of Enterprise keywords

Tags: 2010, taxonomy, user-controls

In my project I use ListFieldIterator control to allow users view and change meta data values. I can read values of ListFieldIterator fields with code like this:

```
object value = fldIterator.Item["FieldName"];
```

It works perfect for all fields except Enterprise keywords. It always return string ";#" no matter which value user have entered there. I'm sure that i'm using correct field name and I've tired to use DisplayName and StaticName instead, no luck. So is anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or how can i workaround this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
object value = fldIterator.ListItem["FieldName"];
```

I've not had problems with managed metadata fields when saving from an ListFieldIterator, but I'm using:

```
fldIterator.ListItem.Update();
```

... to save the values.